# WebRTC: can data channel be used to signalling?

Tags: websocket, webrtc

I'm working on a project which implement webRTC technology and I was wondering if I could use data channel to signaling like webSockets or data channels can just replace peerconnection by sending global datas and so I'll need to use webSockets to make the signaling part to the server?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, the answer is Yes.

Let me elaborate: once a PeerConnection has been connected (by whatever means - WebSockets, https, etc), then you can re-negotiate (new CreateOffer/CreateAnswer/etc) and send them over a DataChannel.  This means in some cases noticeably faster renegotiations, especially for cases where both endpoints are far from the server, or if both are in the same LAN, etc.  (Also lower load on the server, though that might not matter, and no reliance on the server maintaining the call state.)

You could also use a DataChannel over a PeerConnection to a server acting as conference hub or signaling server both for renegotiations (in a conference) and to initiate a connection with someone else connected to the hub or server.

The answer is No if it's "I want to connect directly to someone else random without going through a server"; you need a connected PeerConnection first.  You can use [IPoAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_over_Avian_Carriers) if you want to exchange the offer and answer.  After that per above you can use DataChannels (it will likely be a bit faster).

Comment: I'd love to see ICE used with IPoAC...  But probably best to keep it for signaling.

Answer (score 0):

I think **No**!!!

Because for first handshake, you need a server for signalling.

And I think without handshake, we will unable to share text or files using **DataChannel**.

I did same thing with [this JavaScript Only WebRTC Experiment](https://webrtc-experiment.appspot.com/javascript/)! -- See [source code](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/JavaScript-Only). Where I used [PubNub](http://www.pubnub.com/) for signalling and **ICE** exchange.

Comment: Muaz is right. DataChannel is an API for communication of arbitrary streaming data; RTCPeerConnection is for audio and video streams. Both need signalling to coordinate communication by exchanging media and network information, via some other mechanism such as WebSocket.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by jesup, the answer is yes.

Signaling can happen over any transport. I recommend using websockets since most of the [browsers support it](http://caniuse.com/websockets).

If you don't want to go through the hassle of setting up your own signaling server, you can use Pubnub or [Pusher](http://pusher.com) to handle that for you.

Here's a [webRTC signaling](http://pusher.com/tutorials/webrtc_chat) tutorial if you are interested in learning more.

http://pusher.com/tutorials/webrtc_chat

disclaimer: I work at Pusher.